# How to include a variable and exclude numbers[0-9] and letters[a-zA-Z] in RegExp?

Tags: javascript

I have a code that generates a random letter based on the word and I have tried to create a RegExp code to turn all the letters from the word to `'_'` except the randomly generated letter from the word.

```
const word = "Apple is tasty"
const randomCharacter = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)]

regex = new RegExp(/[^${randomCharacter}&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":;*?<>{}\s]/gi)
hint = word.replace(regex,'_')
```

I want to change all the letters to `'_'` except the randomly generated word. The above code for some reason does not work and shows the result: `A___e __ ta_t_` and I'm not able to figure out what to do.

The final result I want is something like this: `A____ __ _a___`

Is there a way with regex to change all the alphabets and numbers `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g'` to `'_'` except the randomly generated letter?

I'm listing all the expressions I want to include on my above code because I'm not able to figure out a way to do include and exclude at the same time using the variable with regex.

Comment: You can't do string interpolation inside of a RegExp literal (`/.../`).

Comment: You might find using `map` would be much easier than using regEx,   regEx is great, but it's not always the best tool for the job.

Comment: Dunno, for me this just looks way easier -> `[..."Apple is tasty"].map(m => m.toUpperCase() == 'A' ? m : '_').join("")`

Comment: There are 2 ways to create a regex object in javascript. The first way is by calling `new RegExp("some definition", modifiers)`, the second way is by using the literal syntax `/some definition/modifiers`. You are doing **both**, and then the inner one (that uses the literal syntax) is first converted to a string and that string is then used by the `new Regexp()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do string interpolation inside of a RegExp literal (`/.../`). Meaning your placeholder `${randomCharacter}` will not evaluate to its value in the template, but is instead interpreted literally as the string "${randomCharacter}".

If you want to use template literals, initialize your `regex` variable with a `RegExp` constructor instead, like:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`[^${randomCharacter}&\\/\\\#,+()$~%.'":;*?<>{}\\s]`, "gi");
```

See the [MDN RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for an explanation on the differences between the literal notation and constructor function, most notably:

> The constructor of the regular expression object [...] results in runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when [...] you don't know the pattern and obtain it from another source, such as user input.

Comment: need to double up your escapes. ``[^${randomCharacter}&\\/\\\#,+()$~%.'":;*?<>{}\\s]``

Answer (score 0):

`/(?:[^A\s])/`

test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GxFVKL/2)

just replace `A` in `[^A\s]` with you character that you want to ommit from replacement

demo:

```js
const word = "Apple is tasty";
const randomCharacter = 'a';//word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];

regex = new RegExp('(?:[^' + randomCharacter + '\\s])', 'gi');
hint = word.replaceAll(regex, '_');

console.log(hint)
```